# Any program to tunnel MS-DOS application through internet?

Tags: web, remote-access, ms-dos

How to make legacy MS-DOS application accessible remotely through internet retaining it's command line mode - so the remote site feels like accessing that application locally?

It's a MS-DOS legacy accounting application, made using FOXPRO for DOS deployed at every branch office. Everyday, central office accessed every branch remotely through logMeIn.

logmeIn, Remote Desktop send updated screen parts in bitmap. What I need is a program that send only character screen update to save bandwidth and make remote client seem more responsive.

Porting app is out of question, while ssh doesn't facilitate output from MS-DOS based apps.

Comment: Are you running it through some virtual machine? If so, then you can use OpenVPN (with say PingBuster or any other alternative or setup your own) tunnel the virtual machine.

Comment: I would suggest virtualization as well, such as vCD and you can allow console access to your dos vm.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Remote Desktop Services for Windows.  You can publish an app in a window rather than an entire desktop.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/windows-server/remote-desktop-services.aspx